# copy an exported dump file to a target DB instance - LOG

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds

I just imported data into an Amazon RDS DB instance using this guide

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html

But in the source DB the number of tables is 309 whereas that for the target DB is only 4

```
select count('1') from dba_tables where owner='NUNITO';
```

Is there a way to see the log files ?

I used

```
DECLARE
hdnl NUMBER;
BEGIN
hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN( operation => 'EXPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name=>null);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( handle => hdnl, filename => 'sample.dmp', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( handle => hdnl, filename => 'exp.log', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_log_file);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(hdnl,'SCHEMA_EXPR','IN (''SCHEMA_1'')');
DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(hdnl);
END;
/
```

Comment: Of course, you can transfer the log files using the method described in Step 5.

Comment: That guide lists multiple ways to import data (e.g. DMS, data pump). Which did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a list of the files in the DATA_PUMP_DIR directory by running

```
 select * from table(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR('DATA_PUMP_DIR')) order by filename;
```

Additionally, you can read the contents of the file by using

```
select * from table(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.READ_TEXT_FILE('DATA_PUMP_DIR','filename.log'));
```

(Credit for the last script goes to: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28961936/open-a-file-on-a-remote-server-amazon-rds-oracle.html)

I hope it helps